# looping through a directory in bat, going up a directory using bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a bat file which part of looks like:

```
set test=test
for /d %%x in (..\*.%test%) do xcopy "%%x" c:\path\%test%\%%x\ /S /E /F
xcopy ..\dir c:\path\%test%\dir\ /S /E /F
```

The for loop does not work, but the xcopy does.  If I move the contents of the directory above to the current directory and change the code to remove the "..\":

```
for /d %%x in (*.%test%) do xcopy "%%x" c:\path\%test%\%%x\ /S /E /F
```

it works.  Can someone please tell me why the bat script in the for loop cannot look up a directory?  Am I approaching this wrong?

**EDIT**:  I have now changed the command to after seeing ths answer but it still does not work:

```
for /d %%~nxx in (..\*.%MUI%) do xcopy "%%~nxx" c:\temp\%test%\%%~nxx\ /S /E /F
```

I receive the error:

```
%~nxx was unexpected at this time
```

**EDIT #2:**
I still cannot get it to work, my commands have looked like

```
for /d %%x in (..\*.%test%) do xcopy "%%~nxx" c:\temp\%test%\%%~nxx\ /S /E /F

for /d %%x in (..\*.%test%) do xcopy "%%x" c:\temp\%test%\%%~nxx\ /S /E /F
```

Answer (score 0):

It can. But `%%x` will contain `..\xyz.test`, not `xyz.test`, which is probably not what you want in your xcopy target.

Replace it with `%%~nxx` (for "Name and eXtension of x") to chop of the path.

`for /d %%x in (..\*.%test%) do xcopy "%%x" c:\path\%test%\%%~nxx\ /S /E /F`

Comment: Can you type out the line?  I am confused as to where to change to %%~nxx

Comment: Did you use a double percent sign? Did you put that in the xcopy target part? Maybe use an uppercase variable, as the lowercase x might conflict with the ~x identifier.

Comment: You only want that in the last part, of course! Not everywhere.

Comment: Edit number 2, im trying to post stuff here but it doesnt work